# Passing multiple types of values to functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, 2d

The user will enter the values for row and step. The variables for `R`, `Row` and `step` have to be manipulated using functions then printed in `int main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Direction(char z) {
  printf("Walking to the right\n");
  z = getchar();
}

void RowAndSteps(char z, int c, int f) {
  if (z == 'R') {
    printf("Row\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    printf("Steps");
    scanf("%d", &f);
  }
}

void print(char a[4][4]) {
  int i, k;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      printf("%c ", a[i][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  char a[4][4] = {
      { '*', '*', '*', '*' },
      { '*', '*', '*', '*' },
      { '*', '*', '*', '*' },
      { '*', '*', '*', '*' } };

  Direction(z);
  RowAndSteps(z, c, f);
  a[c][f] = 'O';

  print(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: BTW the `Direction(foo)`; wont change the value of  `foo`. In C parameters are passed by value. You need pointers to do what you want.

Comment: There is no `z`, `c` and `f` in your main function. Look at your compiler errors: http://ideone.com/ougd7K

Comment: when I write char z, int c , f; I get an error "these values are uninitialized. What's the correct way to initialize them? Thanks

Comment: is there a way to do it without using pointers?

Comment: Posted code does not compile.

Comment: Yep I need help identifying my errors in my code. I hope someone can give me any helpful advice. Someone told me there are ways to execute it correctly without using pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to get a good book so that you can learn about the C programming language. In particular, the problems in your code above seem rooted in misunderstandings about variable scope and how variables are passed to and from functions. When you pass a variable to a function in C, inside the function you are working with a copy of the variable. This copy is destroyed when the function exits, so you need to either return values of interest, or store them in memory using pointers.

I have fixed up your code, doing the minimum amount necessary to make it run. I changed the formatting a bit to make it more readable, and broke your `RowAndSteps()` function into two functions (because C only allows a function to return one value). I added declarations where necessary. The new functions are only passed information that they need, and they each return a value. Your `print()` function was fine-- you correctly gave it an array, and it doesn't need to return a value.

There are plenty of problems left for you to solve. For example, how should your program handle malformed input? What if the user tries to walk off of the 4X4 grid?

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char direction(void)
{
  printf("Walking to the right\n");

  return getchar();
}

int getRow(char z)
{
    int c;

    if (z == 'R') {
        printf("Row: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
    }

    return c;
}

int getSteps(char z)
{
    int f;

    if (z == 'R') {
        printf("Steps: ");
        scanf("%d", &f);
    }

    return f;
}

void print(char a[4][4])
{
    int i, k;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            printf("%c ", a[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char z;
    int c, f;  
    char a[4][4] = {
        { '*', '*', '*', '*' },
        { '*', '*', '*', '*' },
        { '*', '*', '*', '*' },
        { '*', '*', '*', '*' }
    };

    z = direction();
    c = getRow(z);
    f = getSteps(z);

    a[c][f] = 'O';

    print(a);

    return 0;
}
```

If you absolutely must use one function to get both `c` and `f`, you could declare an `input[]` array in main, and pass it to your function to hold the values. Here is how that would work.

Add this function definition to your code above `main()`:

```
void getRowsAndSteps(int input[2], int z)
{
    if (z == 'R') {
        printf("Row: ");
        scanf("%d", &input[0]);
        printf("Steps: ");
        scanf("%d", &input[1]);
    }
}
```

This function prompts the user to enter two integers, and stores the values in the `input[]` array. How can the rest of the program see the array if everything passed to the function is a copy? Well, arrays are special, and we say that they "decay" to pointers when passed to a function. So you are really working with a pointer here, you just don't know it. This is one of those details that you need to learn about in order to use C effectively.

Add this declaration, initializing the `input[]` array to zeros, to the other declarations in `main()`:

```
int input[2] = {0};
```

Then change the body of `main()` to assign values to `c` and `f` from the `input[]` array:

```
    z = direction();
//    c = getRow(z);
//    f = getSteps(z);
    getRowsAndSteps(input, z);
    c = input[0];
    f = input[1];
```

If you are using this, you no longer need the definitions for `getRow()` and `getSteps()`, so you can delete them (and the commented-out calls to them) if you want. Also, there is nothing here that requires `stdlib.h`, so you might remove that too (unless you are planning on using that later).

Comment: Ty I really appreciate it.

Comment: @FruitPunchSamurai-- If this was useful, please consider giving me an upvote and/or accepting my answer :)

Comment: It was very useful, I still have to add more conditions to it but I did not have a clue how to pass these values from a function to main.

Comment: Functions in C have a return value (which might be `void`), and they can return at most one value. Essentially, when you pass values into a function, those values are copies inside the function. These copies are destroyed when the function exits, so you must either return any necessary information, or use pointers, which allow you to modify values stored in memory. It appears that you were trying to modify variables inside of functions, so this is why commenters were saying that you needed pointers.

Comment: @FruitPunchSamurai-- I have updated my answer above to include a method of using only one function to input both the Row value and the Steps value using an array.